# iPhone cookies to store username and password

Tags: iphone, cookies, authentication

I have no idea how to store username and password details so that the user does not have to login everytime for the iPhone app.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction? I can't seem to find what to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the Keychain API. It will encrypt the data (not hash, as if you have to send it a the server, then the hash wouldn't be any use).

It's a bit of a pain, so take a look at some of sample code and 3rd-party wrappers available on the internet.

Comment: To store username/password secure, Which one is best, NSUserDefaults OR Keychain ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Core Data or SQLite or any other storage (XML, JSON), since there are no cookies in iPhone.

Core Data

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html

SQLite

http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

Also remember to hash the password you should use MD5 at least.